# Django model update based on json url request and unique values

Tags: python, json, django

I made a method to request a json from a url, get some values from and after this populate my `objectidServer` field from my `ImagemServer()` Django model. The main purpose is to populate new fields every time this json update. So for example: If someone for any reason delete a a value from this the field the method will request and populate the field again, based on the objectidServer value (if the same value exists do nothing, if not, create). Same to get new values and populate new fields every json update.

> models.py

```
class ImagemServer(models.Model):
    objectidServer = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    tx_sensor = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    nr_ano = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

> views.py

```
def GIS(request): 
    response = requests.get('url')
    geodata = response.json()

    id_obj = [(data['attributes']['OBJECTID']) for data in geodata['features']]

    try:
        for lista in id_obj:
            ImagemServer.objects.get(objectidServer=lista)
        return HttpResponse('OK')

    except ImagemServer.DoesNotExist:
        for lista2 in id_obj:
            imagemServer_list = ImagemServer()
            obj = ImagemServer(objectidServer=lista2)
            #print(lista2)
            #print(imagemServer_list.objectidServer)
            if imagemServer_list.objectidServer != lista2:
                for lista3 in id_obj:
                    print(lista3)
                    obj = None
                    obj = ImagemServer()
                    obj.objectidServer = lista3
                    obj.save()
                return HttpResponse("UPDATED")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("OK")
```

> json example

```
"features": [
  {
   "attributes": {
    "OBJECTID": 1,
    "Name": "1324_150612",
    "MinPS": 0,
    "MaxPS": 2.245788210298803e-005,
    "LowPS": 2.2457882102988031e-006,
    "HighPS": 2.2457882102988031e-006,
    "Category": 1,
    "Tag": "Dataset",
    "GroupName": "",
    "ProductName": "",
    "CenterX": -56.584631153437641,
    "CenterY": -17.062917718639063,
    "ZOrder": null,
    "NR_ANO": 2014,
    "TX_SENSOR": "TEST",
   }
}]
```

The script works well and I can populate all the fields, but I got a problem when I delete any field: when I request the json again the method not check if values exists and populate everything again, duplicating the entries. When nothings got deleted nothing happen even with the json is updated. Really don't know what I missing here.

> Relations

```
objectidServer (Model) -> OBJECTID (json)
name (Model) -> Name (json)
tx_sensor (Model) -> TX_SENSOR (json)
nr_ano (Model) -> NR_ANO (json)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script is a little complicated and your try / except and multiple loops are not always behaving as you expect. E.g. as soon as the first object is not found in the try part you are starting a new looping in the except part.

I would suggest a different approach:

Step 1: Delete all objects not existing any more

Step 2: Add the missing objects.

This could look like this:

```
def GIS(request): 
    response = requests.get('url')
    geodata = response.json()

    id_obj = [(data['attributes']['OBJECTID']) for data in geodata['features']]

    # Delete objects not existing any more
    deleted = ImagemServer.objects.exclude(objectidServer__in=id_obj).delete()
    res = list(ImagemServer.objects.values_list('objectidServer', flat=True))

    # Add new objects
    new_ids_list = [x for x in id_obj if x not in res]
    new_servers = [ImagemServer(objectidServer=x) for x in new_ids_list]
    ImagemServer.objects.bulk_create(new_servers)

    if deleted or new_ids_list:
        return HttpResponse('Updated')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Comment: Hi Chris, many thanks for your help and support. With this approach the entries duplicate every-time I call the method (probably in objectidServer__in this happens, what do you think?). If I need to update another field for the same entry (example for a new field `name` for the same entry in the model) can I do the same way? Here is the workflow: The code that we are talking check if OBJECTID exists in objectidServer field -> if no, create, if yes just check if the others fields are empty and update them based on the relation from the OBJECTID-objectidServer value in the json-model).

Comment: Hi @vcruvinelr, if the model is as you posted the approach I posted does not duplicate anything. The first part deletes all ```ImagemServer``` objects with an ```objectidServer``` value which is not in the id_ob list. The second part adds new ```ImagemServer``` objects only for those ```objectidServer``` values which are not in the database yet. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Regarding the second part of your comment: Could you post your full ImagemServer model and a sample of your Json data?

Comment: I just updated the code in my main question, put the relations and a json example. The intention is to get the OBJECTID and others fields from the json, populate the fields based on the updated model (already done with your support) and after update in real time. For example: check if OBJECTID exists in objectidServer field (create if not or delete if do not exist in json anymore) populate the others fields from the model with the respective values (based on OBJECTID existence). If any value is deleted or updated from any field them the code update to the json values again.

Comment: In order to update the fields you can - after having all objects created / deleted -  loop through all your json data, fetch the ```ImagemServer``` object, check is it needs updating and update it if required. However, this needs many database hits which could be expensive. Or do it the other way round: Iterate thorugh a queryset of all ```ImagemServer``` objects, push the updated objects into a list and do a bulk_update at the end.

Comment: I already updated my code using your instructions and everything works perfectly. My choice (for performance reasons) was to iterate thorugh a QuerySet. I will study more to understand all the steps you helped me. Many thanks for your time, instructions and patience, hope I can help you back someday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210074/discussion-between-vcruvinelr-and-chris).